# exception thrown in ASP when trying to use Membership.GetUser()

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

So im using this code:

```
var userEmailAddr = "No Email";

if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    try
    {
        MembershipUser currentUser;

        currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        userEmailAddr = currentUser.Email;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        userEmailAddr = ex.ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    if (Request.QueryString["acEmail"] != null)
    {
        userEmailAddr = Request.QueryString["acEmail"];
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
}
```

But I get this exception:

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error Number:-1,State:0,Class:20 at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString) at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username) at ASP._Page_Views_ManagePreferences_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\nopsite\Presentation\Nop.Web\Views\ManagePreferences\Index.cshtml:line 23

Anyone know how I might fix it, it does not make sense to me.

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not an image. If you read it; it says the server was not found or was not accessible. Your posted code has nothing to do with the error; it's crashing because it's unable to connect to the database.

Comment: You probably have Membership configured to use SQL server database but connection string or credentials are wrong

Comment: @Rob will update my question for you with text not image :) This is where I'm a bit stuck as I have downloaded nopcommerce source code, so shouldn't it have a detabase attached as part of the solution

Comment: @WebDevGuy Nopcommerce requires a database. When it's first launched, it will present you with a configuration page to setup the DB. Somewhere along the line, you've provided an incorrect connection string (or the DB is no longer available)

Comment: @Rob When I set it up I used Integrated Windows Authentication

Comment: I also selected the radio tab for Use built-in data storage (SQL Server Compact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to get the users email address in the wrong way.
As I'm using nopCommerce I nneded this code:

```
var workContext = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>();
string userEmail = workContext.CurrentCustomer.Email;
```

Hope this helps someone :)